# FastAPI Resource Expansion

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, pydantic

Resource expansion in a REST API allows the caller to specify child entities which should be expanded.

For example,

- `GET /user/5` => `{"name": "John", "team_id": 10, "team": null}`
- and the user can ask for the team to be expanded inline by adding an expand query parameter: `GET /user/5?expand=team` => `{"name": "John", "team_id": 10, "team": {"name": "some team"}}`

An example of this in the wild: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/expansions-in-the-rest-api/

How would you go about implementing this in FastAPI?
The issue is that FastAPI is centred around a fixed pydantic response model, whereas here the response model can change dramatically depending on the expand query parameter.

Is the best option to just type the child entities as `Optional`?

Comment: This should be possible by using [Union](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/?h=union#union-or-anyof)

Comment: For your example, `Optional` is enough

Comment: Since the `team` element in the response is, in fact optional, using `Optional` seems to express its usage exactly. You can also document the parameter further to give information about when it will be populated.